# Evaluating a double integral regarding the momentum operator

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$ \frac{-i}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{d\psi(\chi)}{d\chi} e^{-ip\chi/\hbar} \, d\chi \, e^{ipx/\hbar} \, dp $ 
Please help me in evaluating this double integral. I encountered it while doing a quantum mechanics problem. I want to evaluate it to $-i\hbar \frac{d\psi(x)}{dx}$
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{iap}dp=2\pi\delta(a)$ simplies your expression to $-i\int_{-\infty}^\infty \psi^\prime(\chi)\delta(\frac{x-\chi}{\hbar})d\chi=-i\hbar\psi^\prime(x)$.

Comment: Thank you very much 